# How to get picture of any location in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, mkmapview

I want to get image of any location and use this image for showing a view. I will look like a `MKMapView` but it's faster (I think so)

For Google Map, there is api to do : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

But what about map of iOS? Can you help me?

**--UPDATE--**

Solution: **`MKMapSnapshotter`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under iOS7 you can use `MKMapSnapshotter` to asynchronously generate `MKMapSnapshot` objects which you can ask for their `UIImage` representation.

Otherwise your best option is to use a `MKMapView` and to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`.

Alternatively Google Maps provides a static maps API.

Comment: This class name sounds great! I didn't see all class in Map framework. About mkmapview, I'm afraid that app will be slower, that's why I want a picture, image. Anyway, thanks your answer

Comment: I would assume that the map image rendering will always be the limiting (bottleneck) factor wether you use a mapview or not.